# Can Linq to SQL create relationships between tables

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I have an existing and live database, it has about 100 tables.

For my application, I'm only using maybe 5 of those tables.

The database *DOES NOT* have relationships set up.

Is there a way to create those relationships in my .dbml file after dragging the tables in?

Also, if this is possible, does it update the existing database? Because I don't want to do that.

Comment: Why can't you create those relationships in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create relationships on the design surface, yes.  Right-click anywhere on the background of the design surface and select "Add -> Association" from the menu.  In the resulting dialog you can select the parent and child objects as well as the properties which connect them.

I don't believe this will update the database, no.  Linq to Sql isn't as bidirectional as Entity Framework in that regard.  Of course, you'll want to test this to make sure.  Additionally, I'm not sure if this is going to result in the expression tree constructing bad SQL against the database.  It *shouldn't*, since those joins can still work even without an actual foreign key.  But, again (and as with everything), you'll want to test it.